# Best regex to fetch street name from a partial address

Tags: regex, ruby

I am trying to extract the street name from multiple examples containing the number and street

I've tried `^\d+(-\d+|\w)? ([EWNS] )?` but this doesn't pass the second test case.

I need these test cases to pass

`2 Main Street -> 'Main Street'`

`5 & 6 Shore Lane -> 'Shore Lane'`

`7/8 Bay Way -> 'Bay Way'`

`73-97 Park Dr E -> 'Park Dr E'`

`2781  Boyle Street -> 'Boyle Street'`

`267 1/2 Brad St -> 'Brad St'`

`433 W. 49th St. -> 'W 49th St'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option could be to match the digits at the start with optional spaces and a character class which will match either `&` or `/` or `-` and capture the address in a capturing group:

```
\A\d+(?: ?[&\/-] ?\d+)? (\w+(?: \w+)*)
```

That will match

- `\A` Start of string
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `(?:`

  - `?[&\/-] ?\d+` Match optional space, either `&` or `/` or `-`, optional space and 1+ digits
- `)?` Close group and make it optional
- `(` Match space and start capturing group

  - `\w+(?: \w+)*` Match 1+ word chars and repeat 0+ times a space and 1+ word chars
- `)` Close capturing group

[Regex demo](https://rubular.com/r/8zIwqME3MClUmr)

Comment: Well organized and explained. Thanks!

Comment: how would I account for strings with more than one space in between, for example - `2781   Boyle Street `. Notice two spaces in between `2781` and `Boyle` as well as the space at the end of the string. See edit

Comment: @Brandon You could use a quantifier `+` to repeat 1+ times a space like `^\d+(?: ?[&\/-] ?\d+)? +(\w+(?: +\w+)*) *`  [demo](https://rubular.com/r/PWDlHXwaE52sDZ)

Comment: hey sorry but I added one more test case that I can't seem to get passed. The main issue is `267 1/2`. My current working regex is `^\d+\w?(?: ?[&\/-] ?\d+)? +(\w+(?: +\w+)*) *`. [demo](https://rubular.com/r/hUjlr0mhHkuZCt)

Comment: Try it like this making the the number at the start optional and add 1+ digits to the group https://rubular.com/r/PLMv6keBKqfJG5 Note that when adding more edge cases the pattern can become quite large.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job: `\d\s(\D+)$`

You can see this in action here: https://rubular.com/r/tcbE7nhNkSQDyS

Basically, we're picking just the characters we want, by defining the rule for the string we're looking for. i.e., a string that may contains non-digit characters (`\D+`), that ends when the line ends (`$`), and begins with a number followed by a space (`\d\s`).